# Google Chrome extension to modify a page content?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am very new on Chrome extension development.

I am trying to create an extension that will append a jQuery at the end of the current viewing page and then will execute some code.

Is there any tutorial on that ? or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chrome by default user scripts vry much like greasemonkey. You can start with that.

1. http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/user-scripts
2. plethora of scripts here: http://userscripts.org/